# Moving sprite from a group of sprites

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uitouch, ccsprite

I am having 15 sprites in my layer.i added these sprite to mutable array i want to move single sprite using `ccTouchesMoved`.when the touch ended `ccTouchesEnded` sprite move back to its starting point or its origin.

My coding:

```
if( (self=[super init])) {

    collection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CCLayer *base=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Base.png"];
    base.position=ccp(512,384);
    [self addChild:base];




    x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        CCSprite *hole=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
        hole.position=ccp(140+x,318);
        hole.tag=i;
    [self addChild:hole];
        hole.visible=YES;
        [collection addObject:hole];
        x=x+75;
    }

    self.isTouchEnabled=YES;

}
return self;
 }
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];
p=location;


}
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"count:%i",[collection count]);
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];


 for(CCSprite *s in collection)
 {
   if(CGRectContainsPoint([s boundingBox], location))
    s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);

 }
}
 -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for(CCSprite *s in collection)
{

        s.position=p;

 }
}
```

when i moving one sprite other sprites also visible on the layer not to be hide.
 please help me with code.

Comment: When the touch ends, you set all (!) sprites to the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(CCSprite *s in collection)
 {
   if(CGRectContainsPoint([s boundingBox], location))
    s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);

 }
```

Since all your sprites are in the same location, the above code is moving all sprites in that location.

```
for(CCSprite *s in collection)
{
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([s boundingBox], location))
    {
        s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
        break;
    }
}
```

The above code will break out of the loop once the first sprite is detected, hence should only move the first sprite in the array.

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but hope this helps.

----edit

Personally what I would do is have a instance variable for a sprite.

```
CCSprite * touchedSprite;
```

and do the following...

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
    location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

    for((CCSprite * sprite in collection)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
        {
            touchedSprite = sprite;
            p = sprite.position;
            break;
        }
    }
}
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"count:%i",[collection count]);
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

    touchedSprite.position = location;
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touchedSprite.position = p;
}
```

i didn't test the code so i am not sure if it will work just by copying and pasting, but i think this will give you the right idea. There are obviously other ways of doing this, but i think its the simplest if you are to do bunch of stuff to the sprite that is being touched.

Comment: You coding is helpful for me while moving. when my touch ended all the sprites are in same position.I also used the same code in cctouchesEnd method but not get solution

Comment: Okay, what exactly do you want to do at touches ended? i am assuming you just want to move back the sprite you moved to its original position... ill edit my answer